# Is there any way to combine multiple framework into single single framework in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, ios8

I have developed few custom framework in iOS,But I want to merge all custom framework into single framework.I m looking for the way to do this. If anybody know please help me?

Comment: Add that framework as a dependency to the other framework

Comment: Were you able to successfully accomplish this?